# why override canBecomeFirstResponder?

Tags: iphone

I'm looking at TVAnimationGestures from WWDC 2010, and in the TableVieWController.m, they override canBecomeFirstResponder:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
```

Is there a reason they do this?  I don't see this method called anywhere.  Thanks.

Comment: Do they use `UIMenuController` from anywhere in the controller code? If so, in order to show and receive a menu, the receiver of messages from the menu controller must be able to become a first responder.

Comment: @gschandler Yes they do use the UIMenuController for a long press on the table.  So do you need to override that method any time you use UIMenuController?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you can mark your question as answered...

They are using an `UIMenuController` within the sample, and in order to receive messages from that controller to your controller, you must make your controller the first responder (and accept becoming first responder via `canBecomeFirstResponder`.

Answer (score 0):

This method is called by the Cocoa framework and not typically application to see if a controller should become the first responder.  While I haven't looked at that specific example, it probably allows the table to be editable.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to override canBecomeFirstResponder in a custom UIView so I could use a custom InputView and InputAccessoryView.

[Custom Views for Data Input](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html)

I had to do it this way because if I used a UITextField or UITextView, a hardware keyboard would subvert the more limited on-screen keyboard.